# How to enable authorization with the Spring Batch Admin UI

Tags: spring-security, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I'm integrating the Spring Batch Admin UI into my batch-jobs application. The authentication to the UI is easy. But I have another requirement to ONLY authorize some users to START/STOP jobs. Anyone with feedback on how to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It would greatly benefit the community if you could post some code together with your question to show that you put effort into trying to solve the problem yourself. This not only motivates the community into helping you, but also shows us what you have already done and what you might be missing. So ... could you update your question with code samples?